# How to upload image writing a form manually in web2py?

Tags: html, web2py

I have a table db.IMG & a field in it called 'pic' of type 'upload' . 
This is how i am trying inserting image in table in default.py (controller)

```
db.IMG.insert(pic=request.vars.fld)
```

And fld is a input tag of type 'file' in a form .
Problem is even though , an entry is successfully made in database , but i cant download or access it . What am  i possibly doing wrong ?
PS : For some reasons i wish to avoid SQLFORM if it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
stream = open(filename, 'rb')
db.IMG.insert(pic=db.IMG.pic.store(stream, filename))
```

It is also possible to insert a file in a simpler way and have the insert method call store automatically:

```
stream = open(filename, 'rb')
db.IMG.insert(pic=stream)
```

Read this - [More on upload](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#More-on-uploads)